# Correct way to authenticate for an API backend on a different domain? (3rd party cookies)

Tags: oauth, express, session-cookies, cors, sails.js

I have a web app split into 2 parts.

1. A javascript front-end. (myfrontend.com)
2. API backend (node.js).  (mybackend.com)

These 2 parts are hosted on different domains, I need it to be this way because eventually I will build out more front-ends for the same backend (i.e., mobile web apps, etc.)

The way I'm authenticating right now:

1. A user logs in from myfrontend.com , the credentials are sent (ajax) to mybackend.com where they are checked against the DB. If they don't check out nothing happens and mybackend.com responds with an error code.
2. If they do check out, I use express.js' cookie-sessions and mybackend.com responds with a cookie (for the mybackend.com domain) . The server links the user-id retrieved from the DB to the session.
3. From then on, all requests to mybackend.com include the cookie, the backend uses the cookie to find the session, and uses the user-id info in the session to respond correctly.

I had a bunch of CORS issues with this initially, but after setting all the right headers (like withCredentials, etc.) everything is working great, in every browser.

I thought this was a very elegant solution, because all user info is quarantined tightly on the backend, the front-end never receives any user-data, only a short-lived cookie.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is this the right way to do this kind of thing? How is OAuth implemented differently from this, and are there advantages?
2. If I turn off third-party cookies in chrome, this stops working. However turning off third-party cookies in safari still allows this to work fine. What's the deal? Why is getting a cookie for "mybackend.com" when you ajax to "mybackend.com" considered a third party cookie? Would it be ok if I used an iframe or something? Should I worry about this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, this is a good pattern to use. I used the same approach in http://hackhall.com (https://github.com/azat-co/hackhall). OAuth is more for a three way authentications: consumer, service provider and your app.
   OAuth 1.0 requires "oauth dance" to get the the access token which is time sensitive. OAuth 2.0 is easier because after consumers get tokens the first time they can be exchanged for permanent bearers that acts as a password.
   OAuth Echo is for delegated calls/requests.
2. Something to do with the strictness of browsers and/or cookie headers?